# Setting default RadioButton Selected with asp.net server side eval

Tags: asp.net

I have the following in a repeater (you cannot use the asp: RadioButton as this breaks the group name)

```
<input type="radio" id="SubscriptionSelected" name="Subscription" checked='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Value")) != 0 %>'/>
```

Where `Value` is either a 0 or 1, this indeed sets the tag in html to have the correct `true` or `false` however when rendered on the page the last item in the list is always selected.

So given 3 buttons with the second button being `checked="true"` the third button displays as `checked`

Does anyone have any insight into why the second button wouldn't display as selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your HTML, I bet you are rendering 3 INPUT tags with checked="true"

From your code, you are checking a value in your databinding to find if it != 0.  Are you sure that you have only one value that is not 0 in your dataset?